# Finding all outer measures on a finite set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

I have to find all the outer measure on a set $X$ with a finite number of elements. I can find a family of functions that satisfy the outer measure definition, however how can I be sure that is are all the outer measures we can have on such a set? Or in general, once we have found a number of outer measures, how do we make sure these are all the possible ones?